# Replace 1st two characters within column that satisfy certain criteria

Tags: python, replace

i am looking into converting the following data from Month_Day within tmaxmin into 'Jan-01', 'Feb-15' etc...

Month_Day max min

0
01-01 243 86

1
01-02 230 90

2
01-03 233 104

3
01-04 220 73

4
01-05 224 71

though i know it is stupid to do replacement like this, may i know if there is any faster way to do so?

```
for i in range(len(tmaxmin)):
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '01':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Jan-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '02':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Feb-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '03':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Mar-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '04':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Apr-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '05':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'May-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '06':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Jun-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '07':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Jul-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '08':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Aug-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '09':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Sep-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '10':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Oct-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '11':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Nov-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
    if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][:2] == '12':
        tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = 'Dec-'+tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][3:5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `tmaxmin` is:

```
  Month_Day  max  min
0     01-01  243   86
1     01-02  230   90
2     01-03  233  104
3     01-04  220   73
4     01-05  224   71
```

Use `calendar` and `apply`:

```
import calendar
tmaxmin.Month_Day = tmaxmin.Month_Day.apply(lambda x:calendar.month_abbr[int(x[:2])]+x[2:])
```

You'll get

```
  Month_Day  max  min
0    Jan-01  243   86
1    Jan-02  230   90
2    Jan-03  233  104
3    Jan-04  220   73
4    Jan-05  224   71
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) (along with https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior as a reference) to your advantage!

```
Month_Day_dt = pandas.to_datetime(tmaxmin['Month_Day'], format = '%m-%d')
tmaxmin['Month_Day'] = Month_Day_dt.dt.strftime('%b-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(len(tmaxmin)):
    dt = datetime.strptime(tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i][2:7], '%m-%d')
    tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i] = dt.strftime('%b-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Month_Day` key appears to be linking to a `str`, you don't need to use slice notation, but it would be better to use the `str` type method `startswith` instead.

So:

```
if tmaxmin['Month_Day'][i].startswith('01'):
    # do your stuff
```

That's a start to cleaning up your code.

Also, tmaxmin is an iterable, so you can just use `for ... in ...:` to iterate through it:

```
for date in tmaxmin:
    if date['Month_Day'].startswith('01'):
        date['Month_Day'] = "something else"
```

Since lists and dicts are mutable, this will edit the list in place.

Additionally, you may want to create a tuple to pair the replacements together so you can have cleaner code:

```
replacements = (
    ('01', 'Jan'),
    ('02', 'Feb'),
    ('03', 'March'),
    ...
    )

for date in tmaxmin:
    for old, new in replacements:
        if date.startswith(old):
            date['Month_Day'] = new + date['Month_Day'][2:]
```